# Какой цикл сработает быстрее?

Tags: php

```
$array = array('Бананы', 'Клубника', 'Яблоки', 'Мандарины', 'Лимон', 'Арбуз', 'Дыня');
        while(list($key, $value) = each($array)){
            echo $key,' ',$value,' ';
        }
        echo '<br>';
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            echo $key,' ',$value,' ';
        }
```

Какой цикл сработает быстрее `while(list())` или `foreach()`?

Comment: только идеон плохой вариант проверки скорости:

> Цикл 1 выполнялся 0.001369 сек.  
> Цикл 2 выполнялся 0.001283 сек.

тестировать надо у себя...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - на каком размере массива у вас такие результаты?

Comment: @ua6xh это на вышеприведенном идеване

Comment: @ua6xh, да, запустил вашу ссылку.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov - сначала вернул 1000 =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совсем все ленивые стали...

[`ideone.com`](http://ideone.com/CeOjos)

```
Цикл 1 выполнялся 0.012182 сек.
Цикл 2 выполнялся 0.008764 сек.
```